# Align image at the base of the line

Tags: graphics

I am trying to add a little icon to a latex table. I want the image to start at the base of the text. Right now, as you can see in the picture, the image is aligned at the top. How do I change this?

[image: Wrong vertical alignment for icon.]

I am adding an image by doing this line inside the table cell.

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/warning.png}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/warning.png}}
```

Comment: That actually placed them so far down that the text got "raised". Can I multiply values with -0.2 or something?

Comment: try - 0.3. Usually the depth of a box is 0.3\totalheight.